# Pictures of deceased

Tags: halacha, death, internet, pictures

I read about not putting [pictures of people on tombstones](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1222460/jewish/Can-We-Put-a-Photo-on-the-Tombstone.htm).

Is there any problem in posting pictures of the deceased(The dead corpse) after his death on social media?

Comment: I read once that it is forbidden about this for the case of tzaddikim but i am not sure about the source

Comment: Are you asking about (taking a photo of a corpse and then) posting the picture of the **corpse?**

Comment: That what i meant